# Why can I not see all the expected headers from a Fetch Response?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am using the Fetch API to make an HTTP request.

```
fetch(url, options)
  .then(response => 
    console.log(...response.headers.keys())); // "content-type"
```

But I can see from Chrome that there are more headers in the inbound HTTP response (Date, Server, Transfer-Encoding, X-foo). Why might I not be able to see them in the output to the above code?

I am running Chrome with the following flags:

```
C:\path\chrome.exe  --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=C:\path\tmp\chrome
```

Response:

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://origin?query"
```

I note that making a non-CORS request retains the headers. Does CORS strip them?

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://origin?query"
```

Comment: Are you fetching from the same origin or are you doing a cross domain fetch ?

Comment: Thanks. From that link: "...a cors response restricts the headers you can view to `Cache-Control`, `Content-Language`, `Content-Type`, `Expires`, `Last-Modified`, and `Pragma`". Does this mean I am unable to pass infomation in custom headers cross-domain or does `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` does this for me, but must be set by the server?

Comment: Have found that `Set-Cookie` is not accessible unless `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` is set... :(